# ModuleNotFound even though its there

Tags: python, django, view

When I try to import a function I created in a different file in the same directory, it does not let me.

I tried creating a test.py and importing the function and calling it and it works but it doesn't work in my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from timeconverter import converttime
import requests, json, os, pickle
```

Trying to call converttime()

This is my timeconverter.py in the same directory as my views.py

```
def converttime(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    if minutes <= 10:
        return str("%02d"%minutes) + ":" + str("%02d"%seconds)
    else:
        return str(minutes) + ":" + str("%02d"%seconds)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timeconverter'

Comment: Well it raises an error on the `from timeconvert import ...` line, since you probably did not install it in `pip`.

Comment: Its my own file do I still have to install it?

Comment: If it is in the same directory, then it is `from app_name.timeconverter import converttime`, with `app_name` the name of your app in which you wrote `views.py`.